# How do i change color based on value of an HTML table generated from a pd.DataFrame using to_html

Tags: python, html, css, pandas

I have a pandas dataFrame which I am converting to an HTML table using `to_html()` however I would like to color certain cells based on values in the HTML table that I return.

Any idea how to go about this?

Eg: All cells in a column called 'abc' that have a value greater than 5 must appear red else blue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Comment: check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html)

Answer (score 2):

here is one way to do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, (5,3)), columns=list('abc'))

def color_cell(cell):
    return 'color: ' + ('red' if cell > 5 else 'green')

html = df.style.applymap(color_cell, subset=['a']).render()

with open('c:/temp/a.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

result:

[image]