# How to use `style` in conjunction with the `to_html` classes on a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have a DataFrame like

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10).reshape(2, 5))

df
#              0         1         2         3         4
#    0 -0.067162 -0.505401 -0.019208  1.123936  0.087682
#    1 -0.373212 -0.598412  0.185211  0.736143 -0.469111
```

I am trying to output this DataFrame as HTML, and was previously using `to_html` like

```
df.to_html(classes=['table', 'table-hover', 'table-bordered'], 
           float_format=lambda x: '{0:.3f}s'.format(x))
```

But then I came across the [Style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) feature, and thought that it would be nice to have a styler for the floats in my DataFrame. Like

```
def colorize(num)
    color = 'red' if (np.isnan(num) or num > 0) else 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color
```

which I can apply to my DataFrame with

```
df_styler = df.Style.applymap(colorize)
```

But now `df_styler` is a [`Styler`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.formats.style.Styler.html) object, and though it has a `render` method, I don't see how I can pass the `classes` list or float formatter which I was using with `to_html` anymore...

Is there a way that I can combine using `Style` functions and the CSS classes / formatters found in `to_html`?

Comment: Is [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849992/how-do-i-change-color-based-on-value-of-an-html-table-generated-from-a-pd-datafr) what you want?

Comment: @MaxU Yes, but I also want to use the `classes` I passed to `to_html` to render the html, and the float formatter; that is my question.

Comment: you may want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511373/change-the-color-of-text-within-a-pandas-dataframe-html-table-python-using-style)

Comment: @MaxU Ou, that looks like a messy but hopeful alternative. Thanks Max!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
html = df.style.applymap(colorize) \
         .set_table_attributes('border="1" class="dataframe table table-hover table-bordered"') \
         .set_precision(3) \
         .render()

with open('d:/temp/a2.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me :

```
from premailer import transform 

html=df.style.applymap(colorize).render() # whatever style you want

html_inline=transform(html)
```

And you should be good to go with the html_inline variable. Emails don't support `<style>` tags in html, the style attributes need to be passed in line.